# python which extensions/ modules need to be installed for manipulating excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, visual-studio-code, pip, openpyxl

**I am currently developing in vs code and I am new to this IDE. So sometimes it is not quite clear when to install extensions or when to use pip for installing modules or basically just import it in the code section**

```
import openpyxl
myworkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("path")  
worksheet = myworkbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
worksheet['A1']='Hello Python'
```

**So that is the reason, why I am getting error in line 1:**`Import "openpyxl" could not be resolved from source PylancereportMissingModuleSource(module) openpyxl`

Comment: VSCode Extensions help you by displaying Python content, triggering debugger... When developing with python you have to install required dependencies with pip. This is the case for openpyxl.

Comment: VSC is not an IDE, and VSC extensions have no influence in the functionality of your python script. Depending on what you want it is clear if you need a VSC extension of an additional Python module

Comment: @Tranbi so I install Pylance or openpyxl in commandline of vs studio?

Comment: [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) is a VSCode extension that you cann install via vscode marketplace.
[openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) is a python package you can install from the command line with `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: Yes, I was doing that. Sadly the error notification ```No module named 'openpyxl'``` came